# Can I create a 'CopyArray' function that can copy 2d arrays of any size?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

In my program I have the need to copy 2d arrays of lengths array[3][8] and array[3][3]. Because of the way I have had to set my parameters I haven't been able to do this in one function so I instead have 2 currently.

```
void copyArray(float arrayA[][8], float arrayB[][8])
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++)
        {
            arrayA[a][b] = arrayB[a][b];
        }
    }
}

void copyArray(float arrayA[][3], float arrayB[][3])
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
        {
            arrayA[a][b] = arrayB[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to condense this into one function instead of having these 2 very similar functions?

Comment: Easier solution: Use `std::vector` or `std::array`. If you are stuck using raw arrays, pass the dimensions `a` and `b` separately, then you can have a single function for any shaped array.

Comment: Use a function template.

Comment: While I agree with the previous commenter (to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)), it could be done by making `copyArray` a templated function (where the template arguments is `size_t` for the dimensions).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Do you mean `memcpy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass arrays by reference, you can usefully specify all their dimensions, and if you define a template function, you can use template parameters for those dimensions.

Like this (generalised for the element type as well):

```
template<typename T, size_t x, size_t y>
void copyArray(T (&arrayA)[x][y], const T (&arrayB)[x][y])
{
    for (int a = 0; a < x; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < y; b++)
        {
            arrayA[a][b] = arrayB[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

This can probably be replaced with a one-liner in C++ 11, but the template would follow the same principle.

Comment: If I may make a suggestion, then you should make `arrayB` constant.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Right you are. (I even made the "reverse copy" mistake as I was testing that... The shame. The horror.)

Comment: This has worked, however I'm unfamiliar with templates. Could you briefly explain what it is doing here?